# Refactoring feedback for Reverse Polish Notation (RPN) or Postfix Notation

Tags: ruby, rpn, postfix-notation

One of the pre-work exercises for Dev Bootcamp is an RPN calculator.  I made it work but would like refactoring feedback.  Any and all help to make this code cleaner is greatly appreciated.

```
class RPNCalculator
  def evaluate(rpn)
    a = rpn.split(' ')
    array = a.inject([]) do |array, i|    
      if i =~ /\d+/ 
        array << i.to_i
      else
        b = array.pop(2)
        case 
          when i == "+" then array << b[0] + b[1]  
          when i == '-' then array << b[0] - b[1]  
          when i == '*' then array << b[0] * b[1]  
          when i == '/' then array << b[0] / b[1]  
        end
      end
    end
    p array.pop
  end
end

calc = RPNCalculator.new
calc.evaluate('1 2 +')   # => 3
calc.evaluate('2 5 *')   # => 10
calc.evaluate('50 20 -') # => 30
calc.evaluate('70 10 4 + 5 * -') # => 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class RPNCalculator
  def evaluate rpn
    array = rpn.split(" ").inject([]) do |array, i|    
      if i =~ /\d+/ 
        array << i.to_i
      else
        b = array.pop(2)
        array << b[0].send(i, b[1])
      end
    end
    p array.pop
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me a fantastic use for the Object#send method.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to prefer avoiding `case..when` in favor of lookup tables. So I'd change your code to:

```
class RPNCalculator
  def evaluate(rpn)
    a = rpn.split(' ')
    array = a.inject([]) do |array, i|    
      if i =~ /\d+/ 
        array << i.to_i
      else
        array << array.pop(2).reduce(op(i))
      end
    end
    p array.pop
  end

  private

  def op(char)
    {'+'=>:+, '-'=>:-, '/'=>:/, '*'=>:*}[char]
  end
end
```

I also don't believe you should only be popping off 2 operands. "1 2 3 +" would be valid RPN, evaluating to 6. The entire stack should be reduced. This also avoids the mutation, which is a good thing, as it follows a more functional style.

```
class RPNCalculator
  def evaluate(rpn)
    a = rpn.split(' ')
    array = a.inject([]) do |array, i|    
      if i =~ /\d+/ 
        [*array, i.to_i]
      else
        [array.reduce(op(i))]
      end
    end
    p array.pop
  end

  private

  def op(char)
    {'+'=>:+, '-'=>:-, '/'=>:/, '*'=>:*}[char]
  end
end
```

I removed the other mutation here too, by using `[*arr, value]` instead of actually modifying the array.

Finally, I'd avoid printing directly from your `#evaluate` method and just return the number. I'd also (again) avoid the mutation:

```
class RPNCalculator
  def evaluate(rpn)
    a = rpn.split(' ')
    stack = a.inject([]) do |stack, i|    
      if i =~ /\d+/ 
        [*stack, i.to_i]
      else
        [stack.reduce(op(i))]
      end
    end
    stack.last
  end

  private

  def op(char)
    {'+'=>:+, '-'=>:-, '/'=>:/, '*'=>:*}[char]
  end
end
```

I renamed 'array' to 'stack', since it is a parser stack and is less generic than just `array`.

Comment: Thank you d11, this is very helpful.  Can you help me understand what you mean by mutation and how to avoid it?

Comment: Hi d11wtq.  Thank you very much for the feedback, but this code doesn't work for RPN "70 10 4 + 5 * -" which should evaluate to zero.

Comment: @Itrainpr you can put two binary operators in immediate succession like that? o_O It should evaluate `((70 + 10 + 4) * 5) -`, which leaves a dangling `-`.

Comment: Yes you can (according to Wikipedia examples).  I think the issue lies "1 2 3 +" being valid RPN.  I haven't found any proof to support that being valid RPN.  I believe it needs to be "1 2 3 + +"

Comment: Wow, old post, but to clarify: `70 10 4 + 5 * -` usually evaluates as `((70 * (10 + 4)) - 5)`. Take a look at the `dc` unix calculator, `forth` or `factor` languages. The result should be 0 as @Itrainpr said. `1 2 3 +` should leave `1 5` on the stack.